# wpf xaml MVVM inheritance with multiple ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am rewriting import masks that have a lot in common, so I want (and must) use inheritance.

I have a basic UserControl with all common controls: (I have left out the grid definitions)

BaseClass.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BaseImport.BaseClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
      <Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text1:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbText1" MinWidth="80"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text2:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbText2" MinWidth="80"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
          <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/> <!-- ContentSource="Content" is the default-->
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- next Row -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text3:"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbText3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" MinWidth="80" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
          <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter/> 
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

This is a kind of Template that gets "used" like this:

MainWindow.xaml (just for demonstration a mainwindow)

```
<Window x:Class="zzz.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:BaseImport;assembly=BaseImport"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="280" Width="600">
  <my:BaseClass>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="Test:"/>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestTyps}" MinWidth="80"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </my:BaseClass>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using WpfApp1.ViewModel;

namespace zzz
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
  }
}
```

and to wrap it up MainViewModel.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1.ViewModel
{
  public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public string[] TestTyps { get { return new string[] { "abc", "123", "xyz" }; } }

  }
}
```

If I have one ContentPresenter everything works fine. But in the BaseClass I have two, potentially more.
Like this only the "last" Presenter gets populated. And in MainWindow.xaml can only be one declared.

How can I put more Content in MainWindow.xaml?

How can I select the right one?

Thanks

[image]

The red rectangle is were the second presenter is located (row 1, column 1) but I want it to be were the arrow points (row 0, column 2).

I want another control in place of the red rectangle also declared in MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: it will help if you add a picture with the ui you want to achieve for `new string[] { "abc", "123", "xyz" }`. judging by repeating markup you can use ItemsControl somewhere

Comment: @David: Why do you have more than one `ContentPresenter` in the template when the control only has a single `Content` property? How are you supposed to set the "other" content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff you put directly in the `<my:BaseClass>` tags is the contentProperty which can be only one.

Why only the last ContentPresenter shows it? Because each VisualElement can only have one parent, so the last one claiming it wins.

However you can create as many properties as you want.

```
<UserControl x:Class="BaseImport.BaseClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
      <Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text1:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbText1" MinWidth="80"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text2:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbText2" MinWidth="80"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
          <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="FirstContent"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- next Row -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
          <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Text3:"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbText3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" MinWidth="80" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
          <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SecondContent"/> 
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>

<my:BaseClass>
  <my:BaseClass.FirstContent>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="Test:"/>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestTyps}" MinWidth="80"/>
    </StackPanel>
  <my:BaseClass.FirstContent>
  <my:BaseClass.SecondContent>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="Test10:"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Whatever}" MinWidth="80"/>
    </StackPanel>
  <my:BaseClass.SecondContent>
</my:BaseClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave the point to Firo, because he gave me the right answer. But I want to give some final thoughts, so everyone can benefit from it.

For the xaml "base-class":

```
    <UserControl 
      x:Class="BaseImport.BaseClass"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
          <Grid>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
              <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Text1:"/>
                <ComboBox Name="cbText1" MinWidth="80"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
    
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
              <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="DB:"/>
                <ComboBox 
                  Name="cbxDB" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DBs}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding DB}" 
                  MinWidth="80" 
                  SelectionChanged="selectionChanged"
                  Loaded="DB_Loaded">
                  <!--
                  here the DataContext can be set differently
                  <ComboBox.DataContext>
                    <Views:DBViewModel/>
                  </ComboBox.DataContext>
                  -->
                </ComboBox>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <!-- the content placeholder -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
              <StackPanel MinWidth="80">
                <ContentControl  
                  Content="{Binding ContentOne}"
                  ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentOneTemplate}"
                  ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding ContentOneTemplateSelector}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
              <StackPanel MinWidth="80">
                <ContentControl  
                  Content="{Binding ContentTwo}"
                  ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentTwoTemplate}"
                  ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding ContentTwoTemplateSelector}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>

          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </UserControl.Template>
    </UserControl>
```

For the "base-class":

```
    public partial class BaseClass : UserControl
    {
      public BaseClass(BaseViewModel _bvm)
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        // set DataContext for all other controls
        DataContext = _bvm;
      }
      #region DependencyProperty
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentOneProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentOne", typeof(object), typeof(BaseImportClass));
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentOneTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentOneTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BaseImportClass));
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentOneTemplateSelectorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentOneTemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(BaseImportClass));
  
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTwoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentTwo", typeof(object), typeof(BaseImportClass));
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTwoTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentTwoTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BaseImportClass));
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTwoTemplateSelectorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentTwoTemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(BaseImportClass));
  
      public object ContentOne
      {
        get { return GetValue(ContentOneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentOneProperty, value); }
      }
  
      public DataTemplate ContentOneTemplate
      {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ContentOneTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentOneTemplateProperty, value); }
      }
  
      public DataTemplateSelector ContentOneTemplateSelector
      {
        get { return (DataTemplateSelector)GetValue(ContentOneTemplateSelectorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentOneTemplateSelectorProperty, value); }
      }
  
      public object ContentTwo
      {
        get { return GetValue(ContentTwoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentTwoProperty, value); }
      }
  
      public DataTemplate ContentTwoTemplate
      {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ContentTwoTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentTwoTemplateProperty, value); }
      }
  
      public DataTemplateSelector ContentTwoTemplateSelector
      {
        get { return (DataTemplateSelector)GetValue(ContentTwoTemplateSelectorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentTwoTemplateSelectorProperty, value); }
      }
      #endregion

    }
```

For the "derived" class xaml:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.DerivedClass"
                 xmlns:base="clr-namespace:BaseImport.Views;assembly=BaseImport"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
      <StackPanel>
        <base:BaseClass Name="bc">
          <base:BaseClass.ContentOneTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Test:"/>
                <ComboBox
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestTyps}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding TestTyp}"
                  SelectionChanged="TestTypChanged"
                  Loaded="TestTypLoaded">
                  <!--
                  here the DataContext can be set differently
                  <ComboBox.DataContext>
                    <Views:ViewModelXYZ/>
                  </ComboBox.DataContext>
                  -->
                </ComboBox>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </base:BaseClass.ContentOneTemplate>
        </base:BaseClass>
      </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

For the "derived" class:

```
    public partial class DerivedClass : UserControl
    {
      ViewModelABC vmabc = null;
       
      public DerivedClass(ViewModel _vm) : this()
      {
        vmabc = _vm;
        this.DataContext = vmabc;
        bc.DataContext = vmabc;  // or another viewmodel that holds TestTyps and TestTyp or leave it for ViewModelXYZ
      }
      
      private void TestTypChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        PropertyChanged();
      }
  
      private void TestTypLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        (sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue = (this.DataContext as ViewModel(XYZ/ABC).TestTyp;
      }
    }
```

That is what I came up.

I hope that helps others.